# Best inexpensive processor for R statistical simulation

Tags: processor

I am choosing a processor for a new PC for parallel floating point computations in R. My tasks are very like Monte Carlo simulations, so the performance is nearly proportional to the number of cores at a fixed frequency. I am not going to overclock the processor. I am choosing between Ryzen 1700 and Core i5-8600k or something of a similar price. What would be the best choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR: The Ryzen 1700.

Since you stated server and used gear is out of the question, have no interest in the extra difficulty incurred by programming for GPUs/add in cards like Knight's Landing, and AVX-512 is currently limited to the expensive Skylake-X platform, it's basically a straight comparison of multithreaded performance at that price point.

[Looking at a list of processors near this price point, the Ryzen 1700X and 1700 come out on top in core count.](https://pcpartpicker.com/products/cpu/#X=24362,36592&sort=-cores&k=33,30,28,36&page=1) The only other 8 core is the Xeon E5-2609 V4 which runs at a measly 1.7GHz on the older X99 platform. Intel's similar hexacores at this price point are the i7-6850K and i5-8600k.

```
Processor   | Passmark | UserBenchmark | Userbenchmark FP | Geekbench 4 | Geekbench 4 FP*
––––––––––––|––––––––––|–––––––––––––––|––––––––––––––––––|–––––––––––––|––––––––––––––––
Ryzen 1700  | 13745    | 1120          | 1136             | 20067       | 24993*
Ryzen 1700X | 14619    | 1171          | 1189             | 20987       | 24806*
i7-6850K    | 14374    | 946           | 1014             | 21792       | 25820*
i5-8600k    | 12811    | 787           | 815              | 22426       | 26724*
```

<sup>*A note on the Geekbench FP scores: since Geekbench doesn't provide averages for FP scores, I selected a given run with the closest-to-average run on the first page of search results run on a computer with a valid identity on an aftermarket motherboard at stock frequencies. [Ryzen 1700](https://browser.geekbench.com/v4/cpu/5992028), [Ryzen 1700X](https://browser.geekbench.com/v4/cpu/6000778), [i7-6850K](https://browser.geekbench.com/v4/cpu/5826916), [i5-8600k](https://browser.geekbench.com/v4/cpu/5979305).</sup>

As shown by these benchmarks, there's a bit of a smattering of who's on top. Geekbench leans towards Intel's single threaded performance being king, while Userbenchmark leans towards Ryzen's cores. Without a benchmark using your workload, it's impossible to tell exactly how things will bench, but I'm inclined to lean towards more cores with a slower individual clock for your workload.

Since none of these platforms use DDR3, there's no real advantage towards shifting towards one platform based on memory. Though there may be a slight platform cost incurred by the need for faster memory with Zen processors (especially with RAM prices so high right now), this is relatively small and outweighed heavily by the cheaper motherboard cost–A320 is a perfectly valid option since you're not overclocking–though you may find that a slightly more expensive B350 board provides some nice creature comforts for just a few bucks.